# Using css and jquery to create a reminder box

Tags: jquery, css

I find the reminder box in jsfiddle is attractive. It is a box contain some message and URL , there is a close button on top right corner. When you click it it close with some animation.
So I would like to know *how to use css & jquery to create a simple box like that*? Thanks for helping me.
[image: box]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please take some time to read through the [faq]. It would be helpful if you'd post some code of what you've tried so far so that we have a basis of a starting point.

Comment: sorry i would post the code i attempted here later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a demo with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLqhj/1)!

The javascript is a jQuery function called slideUp() that shrinks the box by lowering it's height.

The CSS to create the box and the button are straight forward. The box is a standard box. The close button is the letter X, embiggened and moved to the top right corner of the box.

In the comments of the CSS, I go into more detail about what each section does.

Comment: this is really helpful . And i find that the box in jsfiddle will remember you have close the box. So that later the box will not display after refresh once you close it. Is it something doing with session? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) for this. This is very flexible and easy to use. You can check the demo of this on [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).